# invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '

Tags: python, loops

I wrote this code in order to Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product. the code works well for numbers k<38 which is weird, I get this error for numbers above 38:

```
mil_data = "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934\
        96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843\
        85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511\
        12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557\
        66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113\
        62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749\
        30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866\
        70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776\
        65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243\
        52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397\
        53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482\
        83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474\
        82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881\
        16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586\
        17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042\
        24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408\
        07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188\
        84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606\
        05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725\
        71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"

k=0
mul = 1
list_ = []
while k<38:

    for i in range(k,k+13):

        mul *= int(mil_data[i])

    list_.append(mul)
    mul = 1
    k+=1

print(max(list_))
```

Comment: What integer do you expect Python to give you if you pass `int()` a string that contains whitespace?

Answer (score 1):

The leading spaces in the lines of code that contain the string representing your number aren't just indentation; they're part of the string.

```
>>> s = '123\
...    4'
>>> s
'123   4'
```

Don't add spaces to your string, or you'll end up passing spaces to `int()` and it'll break.

```
>>> s = '123\
... 4'
>>> s
'1234'
```

Comment: you are right, thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You have spaces in the string after the escape character. You should replace it.

```py
mil_data = "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934\
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843\
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511\
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557\
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113\
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749\
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866\
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776\
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243\
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397\
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482\
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474\
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881\
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586\
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042\
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408\
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188\
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606\
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725\
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"

k=0
mul = 1
list_ = []
while k<45:

    for i in range(k,k+13):
        print(mil_data[i])
        mul *= int(mil_data[i])

    list_.append(mul)
    mul = 1
    k+=1

print(max(list_))
```

Answer (score 0):

> mil_data
>   ="7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"

You should write it like this above. 
It is considering `\` as a space character, they are considered a part of the string. It should work try like this

Comment: yes indeed! the rest works just fine!

Answer (score 0):

I should have put the string like below:
mil_data =

x="7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"
and code works just fine!